# Flask, Flask-Login and Socket.io: Keep a session active even when not sending requests

Tags: python, session, flask, flask-login, flask-socketio

I am creating an application to visualise some data coming from remote scientific instruments in a webpage. I am using Flask to develop it. Also I use Flask-Login to keep strangers out, and Socket.io to interact between the (client)browser and the server, i.e. to send the data and status from the instruments (in Python) to the user (Javascript at the browser).

Using Flask-Login I wanted to keep the session active for, let's say, 10 minutes. I found this little piece of code in a blog (which I am using also in my application), which refreshes the session every time the user sends a request (a cool use of the Flask's decorator `before_request`):

```
@app.before_request # Jordan Bonser snippet
def before_request():
    session.permanent = True
    app.permanent_session_lifetime = datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
    session.modified = True
    g.user = current_user
```

This works pretty fine when someone is using the application by sending requests. I understand that this means literally going through pages (roughly talking, executing `app.route` while using the app).

The problem is that in my app the user will be actually using just one page while watching how the data comes in and how some coordinates and plots change in real time, which is achieved with SocketIO. This means that if I use the app actively during more than 10 minutes -although not surfing through pages- my session will expire anyway.

Is there any way to keep the session active in these conditions? I was thinking that maybe SocketIO can help with this by executing some Flask command at the server every time the user effectively receives some data at the browser, but sincerely I don't have any idea how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem.

Unfortunately session access in a Socket.IO event is not bi-directional. You can get the contents of the session, but you cannot make modifications, since the entire Socket.IO session occurs within a single WebSocket request, making it impossible to send an HTTP response with the session updates.

The rules change if you were open to using server-side session (which you can implement with the Flask-Session or Flask-KVSession extensions). If the sessions are stored on a server controlled database, then from Socket.IO you can make changes, such as update the lifetime.

If you decide to stay with the cookie based default sessions from Flask, then it gets complicated. I think you will need to stop using the session permanent lifetime setting, and instead write a `last_access` time to your user database (I assume you have a user database?). You can update this timestamp in your Socket.IO events, and also in the `before_request` handler. In the `before_request` you will check the last access timestamp, and if found to be older that 10 minutes, then you can invalidate the session.

Comment: Thanks @Miguel for answering. Actually I have only one user (it's a very simple login) and I'm storing its information in an environmental variable at the machine that also stores the app. Maybe my approach using the snippet I posted is not right. Do you mean it's a good idea to refresh the session every time there's an incoming event, in the same fashion as `before_request`? PS: Thanks for your great tutorials, I learned a lot!

Comment: @SebasthianOgalde what you are doing is fine, but it isn't a solution that works for Socket.IO events, because in those the session is not writable. If you have only one user, you can use a global variable in your Python process to store the last time the user sent a request or a Socket.IO event. Then in your before request handler you can check that and if the last request/event was sent more then X minutes ago, you consider the session stale and invalidate it.

Comment: So the problem is reduced to having a kind of `before_event` decorator. Is there something like that in Flask-SocketIO? Or at least a way to easily update that global variable for any received event from the client at the browser? If not, I think the last solution would be to decorate or overwrite the socketio.on function.

Comment: @SebasthianOgalde there is no `before_event` handler at this time. The closest thing is to use a class-based namespace, where you can override the main event handler that does the dispatching to the proper method.

Comment: If I understood correctly, that means that if I want to catch all events in one I will have only one `on_any_event` handler that somehow (via arguments?) will know which method to execute, right?

Comment: Yes, it's actually the `trigger_event` method here: https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_socketio.Namespace.trigger_event. But you have to use a class based namespace for that to be used.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Miguel, that's exactly what I wanted.